# Querying a Lucene index file

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I'm trying to query a Lucene index file through QueryParser. However I would like to see the format of the index file before querying it. Is there a way to lookup the structure of a Lucene index file, sort of like how I'm able to lookup the structure of a regular SQL table?

The reason is that I haven't built this index file myself and would like to get my way around it before querying it.

Comment: An important thing to remember is that Lucene doesn't have "schemas" - each document can have whatever fields ("columns") it wants. So there is no "structure" of a lucene index like there is a structure of a relational db.

Comment: @Xodarap - interesting, is there some documentation where I can read more about it?

Comment: you can look at the [Lucene index structure](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-lucene/) to see why it's not necessary - a better answer is probably just that Solr (which sits on top of Lucene) allows you to set up schemas. So it's not that schemas are necessarily "bad" or "good", just out of scope for Lucene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Luke, or programmatically [IndexReader.getFieldNames()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getFieldNames%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.FieldOption%29).

Answer (score 3):

[Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) - Lucene Index Toolbox

> Luke is a handy development and diagnostic tool, which accesses already existing Lucene indexes and allows you to display and modify their content in several ways